# Find rows that contains same value on different columns

Tags: sql, group-by, count

The table to find which rows contains same value on two different  columns for 2 rows. Here is a small sample rows among 2k+ rows.

```
id      left    right     
1       3        4 
2       4        1
3       1        9
4       2        6
5       2        5
6       9        8
7       0        7
```

In the above case, I need to get row 1,2,3,6 as it contains 4 on two rows of two different columns i.e (id=1&2),1 on two rows of two different columns(id=1&3) and 9 on two rows of two different columns(id=3&6)

**My thoughts:**

I did thought many things for example cross join on left and right column, group by and count etc.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only a tag for the database you really use

Answer (score 1):

```
with Final as (With OuterTable as (WITH Alias AS (SELECT id as left_id , left FROM Test) 
SELECT DISTINCT id, left_id FROM Alias 
INNER JOIN Test ON Alias.left = Test.right)
SELECT id from OuterTable
UNION ALL
SELECT left_id from OuterTable)
SELECT DISTINCT * from Final;
```

It's messy, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM tablename t2
  WHERE t1.id <> t2.id AND (t2.left = t1.right OR t1.left = t2.right)
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5d648f65cc87fd0ae2899e73a9490226).
Results:

| id | left | right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 9 |
| 6 | 9 | 8 |